Handling Kafka Consumer Lifecycle When Scaling to Zero with KEDA in Kubernetes
I’m working on a system where we use Kafka to send tasks to background workers that process these tasks in a Kubernetes (K8s) environment. We’ve set it up so that these workers scale down to zero when there’s no lag in the Kafka topics, and we’re using KEDA (https://keda.sh/) which monitors Kafka lag and scales the workers up when traffic arrives.
The issue we’re running into is that when we scale the workers to zero, the Kafka consumers get marked as dead after the offset retention period expires because no consumers are active during that time. To keep the consumer groups from being marked as dead, we’ve added a heartbeat cron job that sends a heart beat message to all Kafka topics once a day to make sure the consumer group stays alive.
This works, I’m looking for a better way to handle this. Ideally, I’d like to avoid having to send these dummy messages just to keep the consumer group alive.
Any advice or suggestions would be super helpful!
